# jquery select element by regex id

Tags: jquery, regex

how can i use a Regex to select all checkboxes that have ids like

`edit-field-media-en-cat-value-1080-children-1122-children-1249-checkbox`

`edit-field-media-en-cat-value-1080-children-1125-children-1259-checkbox`

and

`edit-field-media-en-cat-value-1080-children-1249-checkbox`

`edit-field-media-en-cat-value-1080-children-1122-checkbox`

Where the IDS (numbers in the middle) change.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the attribute selector and "starts with" :

```
$('input[id^="edit-field-media"][id$="children-1249-checkbox"]')
```

You can even use both the `starts with` and `ends with` selector together ?

Comment: The IDS change , the 1080 change from element to another

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector:

```
$(":checkbox[id$='1249-checkbox'], 
   :checkbox[id$='1259-checkbox'], 
   :checkbox[id$='1122-checkbox']");
```

This way you will get the checkboxes with those specific identifiers (1249,1259,1122) so in case there are similar checkboxes but with different identifiers they will not get into your selection.

So I'm assuming you want the checkboxes of those specific items among a group of similar items.

Comment: ok , how can i get those who have `value-ANY-children-ANY-children-ANY-checkbox` where `ANY` is a number ?

Comment: I've posted a new answer for that, it's using a custom jquery selector to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

To get checkboxes with the pattern `value-ANY-children-ANY-children-ANY-checkbox` you can use a custom selector, like this:

```
$.expr[':'].mychecks = function(elem, i, match, stack) {
   reg = /value-[0-9]+-children-[0-9]+-children-[0-9]+-checkbox/g
   return reg.test(elem.id);
};
```

then use it like:

```
$(':checkbox:mychecks');
//or the equivalent
$('input[type=checkbox]:mychecks');
```

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/437d3) .